# serve static play2.x content from CDN

Tags: routes, playframework-2.0, cdn

In development mode I would like to have assets served locally and when deployed in production I would like them served from the CDN. Anyone using play2 and serving content from CDN be willing to share how they are doing it?

```
// Thinking of something like this in the routes file...
@if(play.Play.isDev()) {
    GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
} else {
    GET     CDNPATH/assets/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="CDNPATH", file)
}
```

(Note: using 2.0.2 because of the headers fix https://github.com/playframework/Play20/pull/276)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those searching to do something similar, I found this link where someone describes exactly how to serve content from cdn using play:
http://www.jamesward.com/2012/08/08/edge-caching-with-play2-heroku-cloudfront

Here is another option, a function that I ended up using so that i could have my local system have application.cdn="" and on production it has the real value.  Also allows version change to invalidate cache:

_assets.scala.html

```
@(path: String)@Html((""""%s%s?v=%s"""").format(
play.api.Play.current.configuration.getString("application.cdn").get,
routes.Assets.at(path), 
play.api.Play.current.configuration.getString("application.version").get ))
```

USE

@_asset("stylesheets/css.min.css")

Answer (score 1):

What I did was just simply edit the "hosts" file on my computer to point the CDN domain locally.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  That satisfies my immediate need and helped me to think out of the box a bit for an even better way to reach my end goal.